# Why does tabbing to a DojoX grid result in a JavaScript "Can't move focus to control" error?

Tags: javascript, grid, dojo

**Problem**
I've got a number of Dojo components on a page. When the user tries to tab from an input like component to a grid like component, I get a JavaScript "Can't move focus to control" error. The user base uses IE6.

**Solution**
The first element in the DojoX Grid layout cannot be hidden. If it is hidden, you get a a JavaScript "Can't move focus to control" error. To fix this, I added a row # that displays. See below.

> ```
>   var gridLayout = [
>     new dojox.grid.cells.RowIndex({ name: "row #", 
>                                     width: 2, 
>                                     styles: "text-align: right;"
>                                  }),
>     {
>       field: "ele_id",
>       name: "Element ID",
>       styles: "text-align:right;",
>       width:5,
>       hidden:"true"           
>     },
>     {
>       field: "ele_nm",
>       name: "Element Name",
>       styles: "text-align:left;",
>       width:8          
>     }
>   ];
> ```

Comment: Why would you want that??? If the user wants to navigate to some input field, he should be able to, wouldn't he?

Do you want to prevent *any* navigation to that field or only tab-based?

Comment: Z is not an input field. I've got a number of Dojo components on a page. When the user tries to tab from an input like component to a grid like component, I get a JavaScript "Can't move focus to control" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
The first element in the DojoX Grid layout cannot be hidden. If it is hidden, you get a a JavaScript "Can't move focus to control" error. To fix this, I added a row # that displays. See below.

> ```
>   var gridLayout = [
>     new dojox.grid.cells.RowIndex({ name: "row #", 
>                                     width: 2, 
>                                     styles: "text-align: right;"
>                                  }),
>     {
>       field: "ele_id",
>       name: "Element ID",
>       styles: "text-align:right;",
>       width:5,
>       hidden:"true"           
>     },
>     {
>       field: "ele_nm",
>       name: "Element Name",
>       styles: "text-align:left;",
>       width:8          
>     }
>   ];
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Preventing tabbing may disrupt partially sighted users who are browsing your site using a screenreader.

Comment: i clarified the issue above. thanks for pointing that out. what other ways could you handle something like this?

Answer (score 4):

If input Y doesn't accept user input, then don't make it an input field!

If you're just using this for value display, use a styled `<span>` or `<div>` instead.

Comment: Agreed. There is no reason for a well designed app to have a requirement to disable the tab key. It's like asking "can I disable the back button?" You just don't do it. It's part of the expected standard.

Comment: i gave a bad example. the issue is tabbing from an input field to a grid component that can't handle it. i'm trying to prevent the JavaScript error from occurring.

Answer (score 3):

I would personally think this type of behavior is a bit annoying. Why are you prohibiting the user from focusing on that field?

A better solution would be to hide/disable the field until it is ready to have data entered into it. You should also have some text to explain why the field is disabled.

Edit: The error message you posted has some results on google, but it seems like it could be any number of issues, this one http://www.francoisfaubert.com/2008/03/06/cant-move-focus-to-control/ sounds like it could be a possibility. Check your HTML to see if there are other controls with the same ID on the page.

Comment: clarified the issue above. it's to prevent someone from tabbing from an input field to a grid component. what other ways would you suggest handling that?

Comment: What is this "grid component"?

Comment: The Grid I'm using is a DojoX component.

Comment: Not an ID issue. Yeah, ineffectively googled, so I thought I'd give it a shot here.

Answer (score 2):

You can set Input-Z as a disabled control. Then, when the user tabs into Input-Y and fill it, change Input-Z to enabled. How can you do it:

```
<input id="Input-x" type="text" />
<input id="Input-y" type="text" onChange="document.getElementById('Input_Z').removeAttribute('disabled');" />
<input id="Input-z" type="text" disabled />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the keydown event and listen for character 9 (which is the tab character). To invalidate the event you simply return false when the user presses character 9.

`function handleKeyDown(e)`

`{`

`var keynum;`

`var keychar;`

`var numcheck;`

`if(window.event) // IE`

`{`

`keynum = e.keyCode;`

`}`

`else if(e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera`

`{`

`keynum = e.which;`

`}`

`return keynum != 9;`
``
`}`

Comment: You have to deal with shift-tab going in the opposite direction too.

Answer (score 1):

After your comments clarifying the issue, I understand you need that user can't focus an element with tab key. Try to add to the element:

tabindex="-1"

by example:

```
<div id="mygrid" tabindex="-1"> <!-- Some stuff here --> </div>
```

More information about negative tabindexes: [introduction-to-wai-aria](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-to-wai-aria/)

Edit:
More information about ARIA: http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the error message: From [Fake's tank](http://www.francoisfaubert.com/2008/03/06/cant-move-focus-to-control/):

> "odds are you have conflicting ids in your document. Also, remember IE 7 and the previous versions are alone to think a name attribute should be treated like an id."

So, firstly, this is an IE-specific bug. Secondly, go change your ids. It appears to be something that afflicted some HP html-based software before, and appeared when the users upgraded from IE6 to IE7.

Regarding the question about disabling focus - just hide any inputs that are unwanted with type=hidden in the tag, and they will cease to be a problem. Never mess about with people's tabbing - it's the one thing that has improved with html over Windows apps.

Morals of the tale:

- Do It Properly
- Microsoft Is Crap At Web Stuff
- Don't Mess With Standard GUI Behaviour

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="z" onfocus="this.blur()"/>
```

Comment: I think that can be very annoying for the user: he'll try and try again to focus the element, but the focus goes to another element always...

Comment: I agree. I'm just trying to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Give the component element a tabindex attribute with the value -1